# Closing Answers?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

On the question [What was wrong with Hitler's left hand?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2455/what-is-hitler-doing-with-his-left-hand) an answer from a brand new user actually garnered a threat of "closure" (I thought answers got deleted, not closed?) for not including sources. Other than the total lack of sources or links, it isn't a bad answer. For all I know, it may even be right.

The answer currently has 0 votes, so nobody has even bothered voting it down. Why not just do that, and say its due to lack of sources? Shouldn't we let community moderation do its job, rather than having mods delete "bad" answers?

I've said in the past that I personally don't like to downvote answers just because I disagree with them. They have to be "bad" in some way. So to me this seems like one of the rare situations that downvotes are for.

---

Based on the mod comments, I now at least can understand why it merited mod attention (it was flagged).

What I still don't understand is why someone would flag an answer for deletion, and *not downvote it*.

Comment: Full disclosure: I do feel a bit responsible here. There was a bit of serindipity yesterday where I had a chance to promote the site by posting this particular question as a link on Slashdot ( http://slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=2937409&cid=40441325 ). My answer got voted up enough that most users would see it (and the link). Its likely that's how this new user got here.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I should have given it more time to allow the community to act on it. However, I had received two flags from different users suggesting the answer be deleted because it was inadequate, and that was what drove my comment. I am going to modify the comment to make it more in line with our guidelines. Thanks!

Comment: @StevenDrennon - Ah. I didn't realise it had been flagged. It makes sense now. Not sure I agree with them, but if you are responding to a flagging, you are indeed just doing your job.

Comment: @T.E.D. way to go on the promotion!